# Web browser doesn't load even with WiFi

Tags: firefox, browser, connection

Two days ago my wifi worked perfectly both on windows 10 and lubuntu. Today wifi works on lubuntu but the webbrowser (firefox) doesn't load. On windows 10 the wifi doesn't work, says "secured" but not connected. It works with cable on both OS.

I flushed and renewed by ip-addres in windows and restarted, still didn't work.

Any ideas?

My ip is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You cand try this, is more specific for windows 10.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bdh-62iHLCE